# Creating accelerator mex in Simulink

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, simulink, mex

So, I have a problem with the mex command in Matlab. I try to simulate e Simulink Model in Accelerator mode, and somehow it is not possible to create an accelerator MEX file for the model. Here is the error message:

**Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Professional (C)'.**

**The specified path is invalid.
Error occurred while processing: -outputresource:Z:\data\My Documents\MATLAB\vdp_acc.mexw32.
A subdirectory or file Z:\data\My Documents\MATLAB\vdp_acc.mexw32.manifest already exists.
Error occurred while processing: Z:\data\My Documents\MATLAB\vdp_acc.mexw32.manifest.**

**NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\mex.BAT' : return code '0xffffffff'
Stop.
The make command returned an error of 2
'An_error_occurred_during_the_call_to_make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I already run the mex -setup, and I have Matlab R2015a and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried deleting `Z:\data\My Documents\MATLAB\vdp_acc.mexw32.manifest`? Is the directory `Z:\data\My Documents\MATLAB\` read-only by any chance?

Comment: It gets created each time I run the simulation. I delete it, but it gets created again, and the same error shows up.

Comment: Regarding the read-only, no, I just deactivated the 'read-only' feature, and the error still occurs.

Comment: Which release of MATLAB are you using? How do you run the simulation? Do you press on the run button?

Comment: Matlab R2015a SP1. Yes, just select accelerate and press the button. 
But I think it should be a mex problem, not only regarding simulink. I took a .c file, and I inputed in Matlab console: 'mex test.c' and a similar error was showing.

Comment: OK. Not sure why it doesn't work. The only thing I can suggest is try in a different directory (not on Z:) to see if there's an issue with that particular directory.

Comment: Just to be clear, was the test.c file that you tried, written as a mex file? (i.e. it wasn't just a random .c file).  The usual test is to find the file yprime.c, which ships with MATLAB, and `mex yprime.c` to ensure that mex is set up correctly.

Comment: I already tried in another folder, still the same. I also tried with yprime.c and a similar error message shows up:

Error using mex
The directory name is invalid.
Error occurred while processing: -outputresource:yprime.mexw32.
A subdirectory or file yprime.mexw32.manifest already exists.
Error occurred while processing: yprime.mexw32.manifest.